# why is my array always selects the number 2 of my array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, colors, addeventlistener

I want to change the background color of my button according to my array but when I press the button, it just changes its color to 'purple'... here's my code.

```
let i = 0;
let colors = ['red','blue','purple'];
let button = document.getElementById('change-color');

function changeColor() {
  for(i=0; i < colors.length; i++){
    button.style.backgroundColor = colors[i]; 
  };
};
```

Comment: Do you expect it to cycle through all the colors?

Comment: As @NickParsons already asked, what are you trying to achieve/what is your expectation?

Comment: it will always choose 2 because you loop through the array and you don't give any condition (if statement) so the loop get to the end and stop on it. please tell us what do you want to happen. on each click the button will change the bg color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser will only perform the rendering steps once it has completed running your `for` loop. As a result, your browser will only show the changes made to your buttons background color once your `for` loop has finished, and so the last color which was iterated on by the for loop (ie: purple) is shown. Instead, you can use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), which will queue multiple tasks every 1000ms, which will give your browser a chance to run its rendering steps:

```js
let i = 0;
let colors = ['red', 'blue', 'purple'];
let button = document.getElementById('change-color');
button.addEventListener("click", changeColor);
function changeColor() {
  if(i !== colors.length) {
    button.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    setTimeout(changeColor, 1000);
    i++;
  } 
}
```

```html
<button id="change-color">Click me</button>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i really dont get it.. should i go back to for loop? or is there a topic that i can review?

Comment: @BryanGabay I recommend you take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0&t=1036s&ab_channel=JSConf) and looking into how setTimeout works if you don't know how that works. You can't use just a for loop for this (that is if you're trying to cycle through your colours and show the changes), you need to give the JS engine a chance to render the changes made to the screen, which is what setTimeout allows us to do (it also allows us to "iterate" like a for loop does by recursively calling the same function over and over again)

Comment: i tried removing setTimeOut because it just changes color by itself. and now i can interact with my button but what i observed is when i reached the blue' and press the button again, it goes from red to purple so fast...

Comment: @BryanGabay can you please clarify what you're trying to achieve? Do you want the colours to change each time you click, or do you want the colours to change by themselves?

Comment: each time i click

Comment: @BryanGabay Ok, then I misunderstood your question. You want to use T.J.'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65465727/5648954), you should accept that instead

Comment: yes i used that too and i used yours without setTimeOut it works fine but ... in T.J.'s answer i still have the same issue as yours that when i reach"blue" and press the button again.. it goes through the array so quickly until 'purple' sorry im bad at english hope you get what im saying lol

Comment: @BryanGabay hm, I'm not too sure I understand. With T.J's answer you'll get the colours going from `(click) --> red --> (click) --> blue --> (click) --> purple --> (click) --> red --> etc.` is that not what you are after?

Comment: click > red > click > blue > click > red,blue,green - it becomes like this instead of just green

Answer (score 2):

Because you loop through the entire array on every click. Instead, only have the click change the background color once:

```
let i = 0;
let colors = ['red','blue','purple'];
let button = document.getElementById('change-color');

function changeColor(){
    button.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    i = (i + 1) % colors.length;
}
```

---

Side note: The `i = (i + 1) % colors.length` code adds one to `i` so it moves on to the next color for the next click, and wraps around back to `0` when it gets to the end of the `colors` array. So the values in `i` will be `0` (the initial value), then `1`, then `2`, and then `0` again because `(2 + 1) % colors.length` is `3 % 3` which is `0`.

Comment: @BryanGabay - No, it isn't. `i + 1` leaves `i` unchanged. `i++` changes `i`. You could rewrite the above to `button.style.backgroundColor = colors[i]++; i = i % colors.length;` if you wanted to use `++`. (You *could* use `++I` in the update expression like this: `i = ++i % colors.length`, but it would be very misleading, since you're updating `i` just to throw away that update via `=` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your code iterates through the array to the end, so naturally the latest item will be selected. In fact your button changes its color 3 times so quickly that you assume it just changed one time.

I think loop is not what you want, you need to pass an argument to the function if you want to select a color yourself. In case of random color you can use a random number generator as your array index.